# Explanation - $\alpha = \sup{(C \cap \alpha)}$

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, ordinals

I need help understanding a section of the proof of lemma 7.9 of the book "A course in Set Theory" by Ernest Schimmerling, more precisely the step where the author says

> [...] Easily, we see that $\alpha = \sup{(C \cap \alpha)}$ and $\alpha = \sup{(D \cap \alpha)}$. [...]

Notice that I have read the other proofs of the same fact, for example in "Set Theory: The third millennium edition" by Thomas Jech, I simply cannot understand how the proof of lemma 7.9 follows from definition 7.8 in the book "A course in Set Theory" by Ernest Schimmerling.

> **Definition 7.8** Let $\kappa$ be a limit ordinal and $C$ be a set. Then:
>
> - $C$ is unbounded in $\kappa$ iff $\sup{(C \cap \kappa)} = \kappa$
> - $C$ is closed in $\kappa$ iff for every $\alpha < \kappa$, if $C \cap \alpha \neq \emptyset$, then $\sup{(C \cap \alpha)} \in C$.
> - $C$ is club in $\kappa$ iff $C$ is closed and unbounded in $\kappa$.

> **Lemma 7.9** Assume that $\text{cf}(\kappa) > \omega$. Let
> $$\mathcal{F} = \{A \subseteq \kappa \mid \text{there exists a club}~C~\text{in}~\kappa~\text{such that}~C\subseteq A\}.$$
> Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter over $\kappa$.

The part of the proof that confuses me goes as follows:

> It enough to show that if $C$ and $D$ are club in $\kappa$, then so is $C \cap D$. First we show that $C \cap D$ is closed in $\kappa$. Let $\beta < \kappa$ and assume that $C \cap D \cap \beta \neq \emptyset$. Let $$\alpha = \sup{(C \cap D \cap \beta)}.$$ We must show that $\alpha \in C\cap D$. **Easily, we see that $\alpha = \sup{(C \cap \alpha)}$ and $\alpha = \sup{(D \cap \alpha)}$**.

Why do we have $\alpha = \sup{(C \cap \alpha)}$? How does it follow from the definition?

My investigation (I will only deal with $C$): Since $C \cap D \cap \beta \neq \emptyset$ we know that $C \cap \beta \neq \emptyset$ *and* $\alpha \neq \emptyset$.
Assume that $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal (there exists an ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha = \gamma + 1$), then $\sup{(\alpha \cap C)} \leq \gamma < \alpha$.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Consider $\kappa$ as a linear topological space with the topology generated by the $\in$ order. Since $\in$ is also a well-order on $\kappa$, the set-theoretic definition of "closed in $\kappa$" co-incides with the topological definition. And if $C,D$ are topologically closed then so is $C\cap D$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's assume that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

If $\alpha=\sup(C\cap D\cap\beta)$, then first and foremost, $\alpha\leq\beta$ and very very clearly, $\alpha=\sup(C\cap D\cap\alpha)$.

So, since $C\cap D\subseteq C$, we have that $C\cap D\cap\alpha\subseteq C\cap\alpha$. Since $\sup(C\cap D\cap\alpha)=\alpha$ it must be that $\sup(C\cap\alpha)\geq\alpha$. But in what way can it not be equal?

Now, what happens if it wasn't a limit ordinal? In that case we really don't care. The problem with closure of sets of ordinals can only arise in the case where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: Suppose $\kappa=C=\omega_1, D=(\omega_1 \setminus \omega )\cup \{37 \}, \alpha = \omega$.  Isn't $\sup C \cap D \cap \alpha \neq \sup C \cap \alpha$?

Comment: @RobertShore: In what sense $C\cap D\cap\omega$ not a closed set, then?

Comment: Thank you for your time but I still do not fully understand. The way it is written in the book, makes me think that, even if $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal, $\alpha = \sup{(\alpha \cap C)}$. Is this true? if yes, why/how?

Comment: @Ingolfur: It is unfortunate, but often times when you're teaching a course or writing a text, it is easy to make "discounts" which might not make sense when someone reads the text outside the class. The point being is that the only problem for $C\cap D$ failing to be closed, is if there is some limit ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\sup(C\cap D\cap\alpha)=\alpha$, but $\alpha\notin C\cap D$. Throw on this the fact that the limit ordinals are a closed and unbounded set, and you got a recipe for discounts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question in the original post is how to confirm that statement in the text that the two $\sup$s are equal.  I think that they are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @RobertShore: One of the reasons I recommend people to not spend time with mathematicians is that mathematicians are trained to answer "your question as stated", rather than help you with the overall picture.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There's something fundamentally wrong there, though.  The claim $C \cap D \neq \varnothing$ is false if $\operatorname{cf} \kappa = \omega$, yet the alleged proof of the quoted statement never uses that fact.